# ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression. how fix it?

Tags: oracle

HOW FIX IT?

```
SELECT 
  RU.KD_UNIT,
  RKK.KD_KDTN,
  RMC.KD_CRIR,
  RMC.NM_CRIR,
  RMO.KD_OBYK,
  RMO.AS_OBYK,
  RMO.DS_OBYK,
  RU.NO_POL,
  RRB.TG_MLAI,
  RRB.TG_SLSI,
  RRB.KD_RKPT,
  PLBA.MPLB_NAMA PLB_DARI,
  PLBT.MPLB_NAMA PLB_KE,
  DMG.MDMG_NAMA
FROM RAMP_UNITS RU
INNER JOIN RAMP_MASTER_OBYEK RMO ON RU.KD_OBYK=RMO.KD_OBYK
INNER JOIN RAMP_REAL_BM RRB ON RU.KD_REAL_MUAT = RRB.KD_REAL
INNER JOIN RAMP_RCNA_BM RCN ON RRB.KD_RCNA=RCN.KD_RCNA
INNER JOIN RAMP_KEDATANGAN_KAPAL RKK ON RCN.KD_KDTN=RKK.KD_KDTN
INNER JOIN RAMP_MASTER_CARRIER RMC ON RKK.KD_CRIR=RMC.KD_CRIR
INNER JOIN MASTERDATA.UPKM_PELABUHAN PLBA ON RKK.KD_PLBA=PLBA.MPLB_KODE AND PLBA.KD_AKTIF='A'
INNER JOIN MASTERDATA.UPKM_PELABUHAN PLBT ON RKK.KD_PLBT=PLBT.MPLB_KODE AND PLBT.KD_AKTIF='A'
INNER JOIN MASTERDATA.UPKM_DERMAGA DMG ON RKK.KD_DMG=MDMG_KODE AND DMG.KD_AKTIF='A' AND RKK.KD_CBAN=DMG.KD_CABANG
WHERE 
  RU.ST_UNIT=8 
  AND RRB.KD_RKPT IS NOT NULL
  AND RCN.KD_RKPT IS NOT NULL
  AND RKK.KD_KDTN=170702000131  
GROUP BY RMO.KD_OBYK
```

Comment: You group by RMO.KD_OBYK but have no aggregation function (such as `SUM` or `COUNT`). What do you need to group? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: When you group by KD_OBYK you can't select other columns as KD_UNIT

Answer (score 0):

Group by keyword will be used if your query has an aggregation function [like: sum, count, .. etc].

In your case your query doesn't have any of the aggregation functions, so either remove the group by or add all the columns to the group by keyword.

Answer (score 0):

All the columns in selection should be part of group by clause. Selection can only contain columns from group by clause or aggregate functions.